# Writing null values into parquet file with mapper

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, parquet

I am trying to do the following:

```
    String x=null;
    Group group = factory.newGroup()
          .append("x", x);
context.write(null,group)
```

With the following scheme:

```
String writeSchema = "message example {\n" +
  "optional binary x;\n" +
  "}";<br>
```

But I get NullPointerException in the append line. Maybe I am missing something in the scheme?

Answer (score 2):

Here the `String` object itself is `null`. While writing to the filesystem it tries to get the value of the object which is causing the `NullPointerExeception`.

```
String x =null;
System.out.println(x.toString()); // Will cause a NullPointerExeception
```

Similarly any function call to the object will cause the same.

Try using `String x ="null"` instead